# Haskell recursive function example with foldr

Tags: haskell, recursion, lambda, fold, partial-application

I've taken up learning Haskell again, after a short hiatus and I am currently trying to get a better understanding of how recursion and lambda expressions work in Haskell.

In this: [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/1IjBT9TSTyQ), there is a function example that puzzles me far more than it probably should, in terms of how it actually works:

```
firstThat :: (a -> Bool) -> a -> [a] -> a
firstThat f = foldr (\x acc -> if f x then x else acc)
```

For the sake of clarity and since it wasn't immediately obvious to me, I'll give an example of applying this function to some arguments:

```
firstThat (>10) 2000 [10,20,30,40] --returns 20, but would return 2000, if none of the values in the list were greater than 10
```

Please correct me, if my assumptions are wrong.

It seems `firstThat` takes three arguments:

1. a function that takes one arguments and returns a Boolean value. Since the `>` operator is actually an infix function, the first argument in the example above seems the result of a partial application to the `>` function – is this correct?
2. an unspecified value of the same type expected as the missing argument to the function provided as the first argument
3. a list of values of the aforementioned type

But the actual function `firstThat` seems to be defined differently from its type declaration, with just one argument. Since `foldr` normally takes three arguments I gathered there is some kind of partial application happening. The lambda expression provided as an argument to `foldr` seem to be missing its arguments too.

So, how exactly does this function work? I apologize if I am being too dense or fail to see the forest for the trees, but I just cannot wrap my head around it, which is frustrating.

Any helpful explanation or example(s) would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the typos and thanks for the edit, duplode!

Comment: By the way, there is nothing recursive about your `firstThat` — just merely because `foldr` helps you non recursively rewrite an otherwise recursive function, doesn't mean you should refer to any function that uses `foldr` as a recursive one.

Comment: Thank you, I see what you mean and of course it makes sense. I have a lot more to learn than I thought.

Comment: Maybe seeing the function written as `firstThat :: (a -> Bool) -> a -> ([a] -> a)` would help?  It takes two arguments and returns a `[a] -> a`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But the actual function `firstThat` seems to be defined differently from its type declaration, with just one argument. Since `foldr` normally takes three arguments I gathered there is some kind of partial application happening.

You are right. However, there is a nicer way of putting it than talking about "missing arguments" -- one that doesn't lead you into asking where they have gone. Here are two ways in which the arguments are not missing.

Firstly, consider this function:

```
add :: Num a => a -> a -> a
add x y = x + y
```

As you may know, we can also define it like this:

```
add :: Num a => a -> a -> a
add = (+)
```

That works because Haskell functions are values like any other. We can simply define a value, `add`, as being equal to another value, `(+)`, which just happens to be a function. There is no special syntax required to declare a function. The upshot is that writing arguments explicitly is (almost) never necessary; the main reason why we do so because it often makes code more readable (for instance, I could define `firstThat` without writing the `f` parameter explicitly, but I won't do so because the result is rather hideous).

Secondly, whenever you see a function type with three arguments...

```
firstThat :: (a -> Bool) -> a -> [a] -> a
```

... you can also read it like this...

```
firstThat :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> [a] -> a)
```

... that is, a function of one argument that produces a function of two arguments. That works for all functions of more than one argument. The key takeaway is that, at heart, *all Haskell functions take just one argument*. That is why partial application works. So on seeing...

```
firstThat :: (a -> Bool) -> a -> [a] -> a
firstThat f = foldr (\x acc -> if f x then x else acc)
```

... you can accurately say that you have written explicitly all parameters that `firstThat` takes -- that is, only one :)

---

> The lambda expression provided as an argument to `foldr` seem to be missing its arguments too.

Not really. `foldr` (when restricted to lists) is...

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

... and so the function passed to it takes two arguments (feel free to add air quotes around "two", given the discussion above). The lambda was written as...

```
\x acc -> if f x then x else acc
```

... with two explicit arguments, `x` and `acc`.

Comment: After reading the last third of your answer it clicked. Loudly. I should have done a `:t foldr` right away. That might have even helped me far enough to realize I should concentrate on lambdas a bit more in the future. Great answer, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

> a function that takes one arguments and returns a Boolean value. Since the > operator is actually an infix function, the first argument in the example above seems the result of a partial application to the > function – is this correct?

yes: `(>10)` is short for `\x -> x > 10`, just as `(10>)` would be short for `\x -> 10 > x`.

> an unspecified value of the same type expected as the missing argument to the function provided as the first argument

first of all, it's not a missing argument: by omitting an argument, you obtain a function value. however, the type of the 2nd argument does indeed match the argument of the function `>10`, just as it matches the type of the elements of the list `[10,20,30,40]` (which is better reasoning).

> a list of values of the aforementioned type

yes.

> But the actual function firstThat seems to be defined differently from its type declaration, with just one argument. Since foldr normally takes three arguments I gathered there is some kind of partial application happening. The lambda expression provided as an argument to foldr seem to be missing its arguments too.

that's because given e.g. `foo x y z = x * y * z`, these 2 lines are equivalent:

```
bar x     = foo x
bar x y z = foo x y z
```

— that's because of a concept called currying. Currying is also the reason why function type signatures are not `(a, b) -> c` but instead `a -> b -> c`, which in turn is equivalent to `a -> (b -> c)` because of the right associativity of the `->` type operator.

Therefore, these two lines are equivalent:

```
firstThat f     = foldr (\x acc -> if f x then x else acc)
firstThat f x y = foldr (\x acc -> if f x then x else acc) x y
```

---

**Note:** that you can also use `Data.List.find` combined with `Data.Maybe.fromMaybe`:

```
λ> fromMaybe 2000 $ find (>10) [10, 20, 30]
20
λ> fromMaybe 2000 $ find (>10) [1, 2, 3]
2000
```

---

See also:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying.
- https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/EFulmer/currying-and-partial-application
- http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions

Comment: I am familiar with both, partial application and currying, but your answer will still help me to avoid tripping over some particular concepts in the future. That's why I upvoted your anser too. Thank you!